# abs() and an alternative simple if statement does not seem to be working

Tags: c++

I want to check if the length of 2 strings differ by more than 2. This is what I wrote.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
if (abs(str1.size() - str2.size()) >= 2)
  return false;
```

Compiler error:

```
1-5.cpp:8:9: error: call to 'abs' is ambiguous
    if (abs(str1.size() - str2.size()) >= 2)
        ^~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Develop
        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:129:6: note: 
          candidate function
    int      abs(int) __pure2;
             ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstdlib:167:44: note: 
          candidate function
    inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY long      abs(     long __x) _NOEXCEPT {return  labs(__x);}
                                               ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstdlib:169:44: note: 
          candidate function
    inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY long long abs(long long __x) _NOEXCEPT {return llabs(__x);}
                                               ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:664:1: note: 
          candidate function
    abs(float __lcpp_x) _NOEXCEPT {return fabsf(__lcpp_x);}
    ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:668:1: note: 
          candidate function
    abs(double __lcpp_x) _NOEXCEPT {return fabs(__lcpp_x);}
    ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cmath:672:1: note: 
          candidate function
    abs(long double __lcpp_x) _NOEXCEPT {return fabsl(__lcpp_x);}
    ^
    1 error generated.
```

Unable to solve the problem, I changed the if statement to,

```
if (str1.size() - str2.size() >= 2 || str1.size() - str2.size() <= -2)
  return false;
```

Even this statement does not seem to be working correctly. No matter what strings I input, the if statement always returns false.

Comment: What is `it` that you speak of?

Comment: Most compilers when complaining about ambiguous functions will also show you  how it tried to call the function, as well as a list of possible candidates. It might be helpful to read through the complete compiler output. And if you can't be bothered to do it then at least copy-paste the complete and actual output, in full and without edits, including informational notes into the body of the question here so we can see it. Also please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that you can show us.

Comment: `string::size()` returns an unsigned value, and subtracting two unsigned values will give an unsigned result, possibly underflowing.  You need to do the calculation a different way that does not rely on possibly negative numbers (which are not possible with unsigned values).  Also turn your compiler warnings on - they will tell you about the problem with the second case.

Answer (score 9):

The ambiguous call<sup>1</sup> is not the real problem here: `std::string::size` returns a `std::size_t`, which is an unsigned integer types, so:

```
str1.size() - str2.size()
```

Will always be positive or zero (a negative value would be "wrapped" around by arithmetic modulo 2<sup>n</sup>, so you will get an enormous number instead of a negative one).

You need to change the way you compare the sizes:

```
if (str1.size() > str2.size() + 2 || str2.size() > str1.size() + 2) {
    // Do whatever you want
}
```

**Note:** With the code you gave, `clang` warns you about this (in a sense):

> warning: taking the absolute value of unsigned type 'unsigned long' has no effect [-Wabsolute-value]

<sup>1</sup> There is an ambiguous call here for `abs` because `std::size_t` is unsigned and there is no [`abs`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs) for unsigned integer types (why would you want the absolute value of something that is always positive?), so you need a conversion from this unsigned integer type to either `int`, `long` or `long long` which makes the call ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

The type `size_t` is unsigned, and subtracting two unsigned numbers results in an unsigned number as well. When comparing an unsigned number with `-2`, the `-2` is converted to an unsigned type as well before the comparison.

To solve this, you can write `ssize_t sizediff = ssize_t(s1.size()) - ssize_t(s2.size())`, which uses signed data types for this computation.

Comment: `ssize_t` is non-standard, you could use [`std::ptrdiff_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/ptrdiff_t) but to be exact you should use Holt's unsigned comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Since `string::size()` return `unsigned` integer. Any arithmetic operation on `unsigned` value will result `unsigned` value. If the size of `str1` is less than  than size of `str2` and you try `str1.size()-str2.size()` the it will return value from `4,294,967,295 - (diff -1)`.

Note : Here `diff` is the actual difference in length.